# Google Cloud Storage - Bucket change notifications?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

The Google Cloud Storage object change notification, using the Google Cloud Pub/Sub topics is quite useful.
With this documentation https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes, I could enable it at the bucket level and could get the object change notifications to my Pub/Sub topic.
But, I could not find any way to receive notifications when any bucket properties are changed, like Bucket labels/permissions/storage class etc.
Is there any way to enable and receive bucket attribute changes?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, notifications for changes to the properties of buckets themselves is not supported at this time. It's a good idea, though.

Out of curiosity, what were you looking to do with bucket property change notifications?

Comment: Thanks Brandon for your quick response. I believe, changes to the bucket like the permissions, storage class etc. should be percolating down to the objects within. Therefore, for my application who wants to keep track of those things for the bucket and objects underneath, I would need bucket change notification feature. I assume, the storage class for the bucket is applicable to all the objects under it .. right?

Answer (score 0):

### Log Based Alerts

However it is not supported directly in GCP currently as @Brandon mentioned but we can enable [data access logging](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/audit-logging).

We can then use logs explorer to filter out actions done at bucket level and create log based alerts to get notifications.

#### Configuration

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access#config-console